# Why do users have different ID formats between the Microsoft Graph API and UserIDs in bot framework?

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I have used **Graph Service** to get user information by email. Here is my sample code:

```
var user = null;
const GraphService = require('graph-service');
const ClientCredentials = require('client-credentials');

const tenant = 'my-company.com';
const clientId = '0b13aa29-ca6b-42e8-a083-89e5bccdf141';
const clientSecret = 'lsl2isRe99Flsj32elwe89234ljhasd8239jsad2sl=';

const credentials = new ClientCredentials(tenant, clientId, clientSecret);

const service = new GraphService(credentials);

service.get('/users/tnguyen482@my-company.com').then(response => {
    user = response.data;
});
```

This would return user which has ID = 9422e847-0000-1111-2222-d39d550a4fb6

But when I use **Botbuilder-teams** to get fetch members, the user information return from which has different format of ID. Here is my sample code:

```
var user = null;

var teams = require("botbuilder-teams");
var connector = new teams.TeamsChatConnector({
    appId: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_ID,
    appPassword: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD
});

let conversationId = session.message.address.conversation.id;
var userEmail = "tnguyen482@my-company.com";

connector.connector.fetchMembers(
    "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer-client-ss.msg/",
    conversationId,
    (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Cannot get member of current conversation');
        }
        else {
            if (result.length > 0){
                result.forEach(function(item) {
                    if (item.email == userEmail){
                        user = item;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
);
```

This would return user which has ID = 29:1zJXjlM7ifjqawGVxXx_4xxx56BFCCIJWfPbWrVDSdxsKUhi9IXyXXYNLOKCLHodN7WgEzz31lBKcZwtWvMzoUw

**My question is why on the same user with different ways approach to retrieve data return different ID format?**

*Besides, my purpose is that I will use the user ID in address for botbuilder to send personal message to user.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User ID is not defined the same within the Graphs Service as it is within Botbuilder. The botbuilder userID is a key for that given user as connected to the conversation within the bot (and is only relevant within the context of the conversation with the bot), and the userID within Graph Service is a unique identity key for a user of Azure AD.

These are not the same API or part of a universal connector, so these IDs do not cross over to one another. Many people create some sort of dictionary of users so that the 2 can be looked up and used accordingly in their application.

Comment: Do we have any relevant document about this answer, @Mark?

Comment: @user964409 for the Graph value you will find it in the documentation, but that's more complicated for the bot part